# How to center many spans over multiple lines, for each line individually?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

See [codepen testcase here](http://codepen.io/Domiii/pen/ENRobq?editors=0010).

I have multiple spans (or other inline elements) of different sizes (in the pen, I am chopping up a long random paragraph into random-sized spans separated by comma (`,`), just so to quickly generate a test case), and they all align to the text baseline. I want them to stay in a single paragraph, but also align to the center of each line.

As you can see, I tried using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but that will put multi-line spans on their own lines:

```
{
  'display': 'flex',
  'flex-wrap': 'wrap',
  'justify-content': 'flex-start',
  'align-items': 'center'
}
```

How can I keep a single paragraph but all words on individual lines vertically centered?

(As to why I need this: I want to mix small images with text. The text in my case actually always has the same size but the images (or rather, dynamically rendered content) might slightly vary in height.)

Comment: The question is really confusing. You write a JS to split your paragraph based on the `,` delimiter & at the same time you say you want it to stay in a single paragraph ? To make it worse you even gave random font-sizes to different spans using `'font-size': Math.random()*3 + 1 + 'em'`  & what "bottom line" are you talking about?

Comment: The "bottom line" he mentioned is probably a baseline of which text is aligned by default. It is especially noticeable when spans have varying height. So his example shows this behavior well.
Please see [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I clarified it a bit: "I have multiple spans (or other inline elements) of different sizes (in the pen, it is just a long random paragraph of random-sized spans  separated by comma (,), just so to quickly generate a test case),"  -  I apologize for using `JS` to generate a test-case for a `CSS` problem! :)  - Thanks also to @Ciunkos for helping explaining my badly worded question!

Comment: @Domi the vertical alignment is already there are you are using `align-items: center`(see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoyzGw)... the effect you see is because of the different font-sizes... so the question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`vertical-align: middle;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) as by default it aligns to the baseline.

[image]

```js
const text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecatcupi, datatnonproidentsuntinculpaquiofficiadeseruntmollit animidestlaborum.";

// chop up text into random pieces 
// of random size
words = text.split(',').map(w => {
  const $el = $('<span>' + w + ' </span>');
  return $el.css({
    'font-size': Math.random()*3 + 1 + 'em',
    'vertical-align': 'middle'
  });
});

$body = $(document.body);
$body.append(words);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried that before and it did not work for some odd reason. I will try it again in a bit and let you know right away! Thank you! :)

Comment: While this technically answers my previously asked question, I came to the sad conclusion that my question was not complete: I actually have a mixture of `inline` and `inline-block` elements (`div` containing `div` containing `svg`). Any idea on how to solve this? [Testcase here](http://codepen.io/Domiii/pen/LbBQmy?editors=1000).